# int.to_bytes returns wrong value

Tags: python, integer, byte

I need to convert ints to binary strings. However,I noticed some weird behaviour with int.to_bytes in Python3 when using 9, 10. Best way to show is to give some examples

Example:

`(7).to_bytes(1, "big")`
returns: `b'\x07'`

`(8).to_bytes(1, "big")`
returns: `b'\x08'`

`(9).to_bytes(1, "big")`
returns: `b'\t'`

`(10).to_bytes(1, "big")`
returns: `b'\n'`

`(11).to_bytes(1, "big")`
returns: `b'\x11'`

Then it's back to normal. How can I fix this and why does it happen?

Comment: In the ASCII table 9 is the representation of the tabulation (`\t`) and 10 is the representation of line feed (`\n`).

Answer (score 1):

`(11).to_bytes(1, "big")` *returns:* `b'\x11'`

No. `(11).to_bytes(1, "big")` does return `b'\x0b'`

*why it happends*

`9` (decimal) and `10` (decimal) are respectively *horizontal tab* and *line feed* in [ASCII](https://www.ascii-code.com/), in `python` these are denoted by `\t` and `\n`.

*knows how to fix*

It is not broken. Note that following code output three times `True`

```
print((9).to_bytes(1, "big") == b'\x09')
print((10).to_bytes(1, "big") == b'\x0a')
print((11).to_bytes(1, "big") == b'\x0b')
```

Comment: Thank you! That really cleared things up!

Comment: Note: You shifted the *ASCII* meanings by -1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Note you are converting to hex, not bin. As has already been noted, you are just getting "\t" and "\n" because those are the common representations of values "0x09" and "0x10" (`tab` and `newline`, respectively).

If you want the hex values, use the `hex` builtin function.